# Error in Chart Web Part when targeting an Excel spreadsheet URL in some SP 2010 document libraries

Tags: 2010, document-library, excel

I have two different sharepoint sites.  On both sites, I created a document library and have excel documents that were exported off a document library from an info path form.  In one of the document libraries that has the excel document in it, the properties of the document showed:

This is the correct way it should read in order for me to do the task below. https://v6infoshare.v06.med.va.gov/programs/systemsredesign/fayetteville/Web%20Chart/Project%20Dashboard.xlsx

The other document had properties that are shown as:

https://v6infoshare.v06.med.va.gov/secure/durham/has/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=/secure/durham/has/ExcelDocuments/Action%20Items%20Spreadsheet1.xlsx&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fv6infoshare%2Ev06%2Emed%2Eva%2Egov%2Fsecure%2Fdurham%2Fhas%2FExcelDocuments%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1&DefaultItemOpen=1

I was trying to create a graph using the "Chart Web Part" function to create a graph from the excel document.

When trying to link the document to a Chart Web Part, it created an error, due to the link that the excel document was showing.

My question is why do I have two different types of web addresses?  The second one looks like an info path form address that was promoted to sharepoint.

I was able to put the one document that had the long address into the other document library and the address showed the correct way.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have different browser file handling settings in your two libraries. Set it to open documents in office client applications to avoid "`xlviewer.aspx`" urls. Otherwise you can simply correct the url manually.

Comment: It would help others if you marked helpful replies as answers